# Can Zenyatta track an invisible Sombra with Orb of Discord?

Tags: overwatch

Does Sombra's use of Stealth remove Zenyatta's Discord Orb on activation? If not, can Zenyatta still see the marker of his Discord target once Sombra becomes fully invisible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**. The Orb of Discord icon above Sombra's head disappears when she goes invisible, however, she does not shed Orb of Discord by going invisible, unlike Reaper's Wraith Form (for example).

[Source](https://youtu.be/HG-LPbXCI0I?t=1m41s)

Comment: It seems like being invisible has no effect on the 3-second fade time once the Orb target gets out of sight, from that short clip. Interesting.

Comment: Meaning Zenyatta's discord orb doesn't work by "Out of sight" but rather by "Line of Sight". Rather interesting.